# proper way of binding a ResourceDictionaries Source property

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, dictionary

The problem I have is the following, I want to be able to have localization in my silverlight app without the usage of the usual resource file (since that approach did not work for me).

Any way I have several dictionaries for each language that I support, basically in the following:

```
Localization.xaml --> for the default language english
Localization.de.xaml --> for german 
Localization.fr.xaml --> for french, I think you get the idea now
.
.
.
```

now when define the merged dictionaries in my app.xaml I would need to be able the dynamically define which Localization.xaml to use depending on the current culture.

I know I could do something like this in the code behind of the app.xaml:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();

    try
    {   ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/assembly;component/.../Localizations." + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        }; 
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);     
    }
    catch(Exception){}
}
```

There are two concern that prevent me form using it however.

First is that it is in the code behind, since I am using MVVM I would like to avoid doing that.

Second is that I have to foumble with the MergedDictionaries, the 0-th dictionary is basically the default Localization.xaml. So if I were to change the position of that dictionary, I have to ensure that I also edit it in the code behind, which leaves room for errors.

So what I did was to write a SourceProvider, which give ne the Uri based on the current culture.

the code looks like this:

```
public class SourceProvider
{
    public static Uri LocalizationSource
    {
        get
        {
            Uri source = new Uri("assembly;component/.../Localization." + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            try
            {   
                ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary(){Source = source};    
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                source = new Uri("/assembly;component/.../Localization.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the App.xaml I can uses this as follows:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:namespace of the sourceprovider"
             x:Class="Peripherie.Configurator.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ns:SourceProvider x:Key="Sourcer"/>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="{Binding LocalizationSource, Source={StaticResource Sourcer}}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This all works fine and I can bascially use the correct source, however rhis will give me the "Value does not fall within the expected range" error, which is kinda annoying.

Also all StaticResources used are not found because of the error as well, so it would show error which are not actually there, potentially flodding me with thousands of error for missing resources

Is there a way to prevent that ?